# splashscreen push notification register fluctuate screen

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, push-notification, splash-screen

I'm developing application on phonegap(latest) and using "splash screen" and "push notification" plugin but splash screen get fluctuated once while push notification registering his "id(regid)".

What i want is hide splash screen after registration in "onNotification" callback like

I start my splashscreen on deviceready event like(Using JQM[latest] with phonegap)

```
jQuery.when(deviceReadyDeferred, jqmReadyDeferred).then(function () {
    console.log("PhoneGap & jQuery.Mobile finished loading");
    navigator.splashscreen.show();
});

function onNotification(e) {       
    switch( e.event )
    {
    case 'registered':
        if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
        {
            navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

but between mean time (registering) my first page shown and again my splashscreen resumes until it reaches code "navigator.splashscreen.hide();"

I want to run whole push notification registration process in background(Under splash screen display).

Feel free to ask for more information if needed.

Please advice.

Thanks for your time and consideration in advace.